# Basis coefficients square-summable implies function in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is some measure. Let $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $c_n=\int fe_n\,d\mu$ exists for all $n$ and assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^2<\infty$.

Does this imply that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mu)$?

This looks a bit like Fourier coefficients if we were dealing with periodic functions on $L^2([0,1])$. For Fourier coefficients a result like this holds, I don't see how to prove it in the general case though.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that $f$ is real valued. I know that $\|h\|^2=\sum|\langle h,e_n\rangle|^2$, but the question is somewhat the converse: Does square summability imply that the function is an element of $L^2$?

Comment: I see that you claim this to be true. Can you prove it or reference a proof for me? For the norm equation to hold one typically _assumes_ that the function is in $L^2$.

Comment: The equality $\|f\|^2=\sum|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2$ only necessarily holds if $f\in L^2$. Hence using this to deduce that the integral $\int_X|f|^2d\mu$ is finite is circular reasoning.

Comment: I see that you claim this, I don't see why it does and I am not aware of any proof, which is why I asked for one ;)

Comment: This seems to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573592/all-generalized-fourier-coefficients-are-0-implies-that-the-function-is-0-a-e?rq=1 
The example constructed in the answer by Nate Eldredge seems to be a counterexample to what you claim to be true.

Comment: you are right. My mistake, i will delete my comments since what i claim is false. I got confused, sorry.

Comment: I hope I did not cause much confusion. I thought this was trivial but I shouldn't have been so absolute, I honestly apologize

Comment: No worries. I too thought intuitively this should definitely be true but couldn't quite put my finger on it. The counterexample is surprising but explains why this was the case. Since such a result does hold for the Fourier coefficients afaik, it would be interesting to know what the necessary conditions on the basis chosen are.